# Add/Remove/update entry between two xml file either using Ant xmltask or using perl scripting

Tags: java, xml, perl, ant, xmltask

Here is first xml file input.xml,

**input.xml**:

```
<Mapping>
        <Common>
            <Apps>
                <App ID = "id1">
                <config key = "Format" value = "PDF"/>
                </App>
                <App ID = "id2">
                <config key = "Logging" value = "no"/>
                <config key = "ExtraLogging" value = "no"/>
                </App>
            </Apps>

            <All>
            <config key="log1" value="N"/>
            </All>
        </Common>
</Mapping>
```

Need to read from input.xml and Add/Remove/update respective entry in output.xml.

**output.xml:**

```
    <Mapping>
            <Common>
                <Apps>
                    <App ID = "id1">
                    <config key = "Format" value = "DOC"/>
                    </App>
                    <App ID = "id2">
                    <config key = "Logging" value = "yes"/>
                    </App>
                </Apps>

                <All>
                <config key="log1" value="N"/>
                </All>
            </Common>
    </Mapping>
```

Comment: Please show the code that you are having problems with

Comment: i am unable to post code. Do you know how to handle - tag not found with this ant xmltask code: <call path="a/b/c">
  <actions>
    <echo>Found a node under a/b/c</echo>
  </actions>
</call>

Comment: Why are you unable to post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`xmlstarlet`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/xmlstarlet.1.html) you would write

```
xmlstarlet ed \
    -u '//App[@ID="id1"]/config[@key="Format"]/@value' -v "DOC" \
    -u '//App[@ID="id2"]/config[@key="Logging"]/@value' -v "yes" \
    -d '//App[@ID="id2"]/config[@key="ExtraLogging"]' \
        input.xml > output.xml
```